# Using intel's __attribute__((vector)) with swig

Tags: python, c++, swig

I want to write a function in c, which I could then call from python. The function essentially adds two numbers, but if you pass an array to the function it will add them elementwise and return. Intel has this `__attribute__((vector))` which essentially lets us do that. However the swig interface generates error if I use `__attribute__((vector))` in the `.i` file. If I don't do that, the function does not take array's as input and throws an exception. Can anyone let me know the right way to do this?

example.c

```
__attribute__((vector)) double add(double x, double y){                         
  return x+y;                                                                   
}
```

example.i

```
%module example                                                                 
%{                                                                              
  extern __attribute__((vector)) double add(double, double);                    
%}                                                                              

extern double add(double, double);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to just export SIMD functions to Python like that. For starters, Python has its own way of representing floating point numbers (and not a very efficient one). Even if it worked, all the vectorization performance gains would be lost in the SWIG interface.

I suggest you move out your performance-critical calculation as a whole to C, if possible, or just stick with normal Python lists/tuples instead of SIMD arrays.